# Duplicate span text into a text field in a form

Tags: javascript, forms

How do i take the result from "#sum" and have it auto duplicate in a textfield so when i submit a form, the value gets sent also?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(":text").each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function() {
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
        var sum=0;
        $(":text").each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 {
                sum+=parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
    }
</script>
```

Is there a quick fix to this?

This is where the actual value updates on the html page.

```
<span id="sum">0</span>
```

Comment: you could use jQuery clone() http://api.jquery.com/clone/ to duplicate the result from #sum in a textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do the following

```
function calculateSum() {
        var sum=0;
        $(":text").each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 {
                sum+=parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
       $("#myTextField").val(sum.toFixed(0)); //adding to text field
    }
```

Comment: actually its not adding right. If i type in 500 in one of the fields it now takes the first number and repeats, so if i type 500 it outputs as 555